# How to make a "typing on" command?

Tags: inform7

I want to have a computer on which the player can **type on**, like this:

```
The Lab is a room.

A desk is in the lab. On the desk are a personal computer and a note.
Description of the note is "Password: wh23".

Typing it on is an action applying to a topic and a touchable thing.
Understand "Type [text] in/into/onto/on [something]" as typing it on.

Instead of typing something on the computer:
    say "wrong password".
Instead of typing "wh23" on the computer:
    say "welcome back, user!"

test me with "x note / type wh23 into computer"
```

This throws the Error: *"but an action can only apply to things or to kinds of value"*

I tried lots of variations of this, none worked.

Is it only possible to have the topic at the end of the line?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but you need to specify the amounts:

```
Typing it on is an action applying to one topic and one touchable thing.
```

The next issue will be that topics aren't considered to be "something" so the first instead rule must be changed to:

```
Instead of typing some topic on the computer:
    say "wrong password".
```